# What do you use for long running tasks since Loaders and AsyncTask have been deprecated?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, background-process, asynctaskloader

`Loaders` and `AsyncTask` were really easy to use and helpful classes for long running operations like performing network http requests, but since they are deprecated, I couldn't find an alternative. I know that I may use `LiveData` + `ViewModel` as Google suggests but they are not doing tasks in a separate thread, so what can we use besides them? `RxJava`? or sth else? (regardless of manually creating `Threads` and `Executors`)

*I use Java.

Comment: you can use coroutines

Comment: What for Java??

Comment: If you need work with streams you can use Rx or Flow (coroutines streams) else you could use coroutines.  Use Rx only to change of thread is not necessary.

Comment: @ManuelMato what do you mean by working with streams, please? 
For example, using Java, if I want to do http request and get response should I use RxJava instead of AsyncTasks and combine with ViewModel?

Comment: A stream of data is a flow of data, emitting them and you need to consume them, for example bluetooth data.  If you want to fetch data from an api, you could use the coroutines using the suspend functions (under the hood are callbacks) and if you want, use livedata in the viewmodel to update the ui.  So the ViewModel launch the coroutine using the IO dispatcher and then you can update the livedata using the postValue method.  Coroutines are easier than Rx and the code I think is clearer than Rx.  You can read and see my base project using coroutines  in proandroiddev shorturl.at/coT02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For performing network requests, the network library that you are using should handle that. All network SDKs (Okhttp, Retrofit) handles the background processing, you don't have to worry.

For other background processes or if you are using your own code to make the HTTP calls like HttpUrlConnection etc, you have a couple of options.

1. Coroutines. If your project is in Java, that won't be a problem because Java and Kotlin are interoperable.
2. ExecutorService: Provides a bunch of useful APIs to push a task into the background and then you can use a MainThread Looper to send the data back from background thread to UI.
3. Handler threads and Intent service: They are standard android APIs which are made for background processing only.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/guide/background

Comment: Thank you so much. One more thing, could RxJava be one of the options? I don't really know about it

Comment: Yes, but I have not used RxJava.